# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un objecto con unos criterios en especifico?

Tags: javascript, json

**Hola a toda la comunidad salud.**

Este código meda este resultado usando la función **sort()**

```
// Get all columns from JSON
    let columnsArray: any[];
    for (const key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            columnsArray = Object.keys(json[key])
            
            columnsArray.sort()

        }
    }
```

**Resultado:**

correo 
enviado 
excel 
fechaSolicitud 
fechas 
idCliente 
pdf 
planes

---

Este código me da este resultado sin usar la función .sort()

```
 // Get all columns from JSON
    let columnsArray: any[];
    for (const key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            columnsArray = Object.keys(json[key])
            
            columnsArray

        }
    }
```

**Resultado:**

fechas 
planes 
correo 
enviado 
pdf 
excel 
fechaSolicitud 
idCliente

yo necesito ordenar el objecto por criterios especifico por ejemplo les muestro como necesito que me quede ASI NECESITO QUE ME QUEDE ES UN CRITERIO ESPECIFIO AL QUE NO NOS OFRECE .SORT() O REVERSE()

fechaSolicitud
idCliente
correo
enviado
pdf
excel
fechas
planes

Esto es lo que he invesitago referente a este tema [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://fernando-gaitan.com.ar/ordenar-y-desordenar-un-array-de-json-en-javascript/)
estoy atento cualquier consejo seria de mucho valor

ESTE LINK TE LLEVARA A UN EJEMPLO TENGO EL CÓDIGO EN ESTE SITIO [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ejercicio-con-objectos-dc3ti?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) si me puede ayudar desde este link seria super genial

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. ¿Cómo describirías ese criterio específico de ordenamiento? Qué revisarías en los valores para decidir cómo ordenarlos? Siéntete libre de [edit] y añadir toda la info relevante que te vayan pidiendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de lo que especifícas y compartes en código, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const json = [{
    correo: "ANGIE.PULIDO@SEGUROSDELESTADO.COM.CO",
    enviado: true,
    excel: true,
    fechaSolicitud: "08-10-2021",
    fechas: "[2021-07-31]",
    idCliente: 34170,
    pdf: true,
    planes: "[{f:25,p:110020904148}, {f:25,p:112690000002}, {f:25,p:112690000006}, {f:25,p:112690000007}, {f:25,p:112690000019}, {f:25,p:112690000025}, {f:25,p:112690000026}, {f:25,p:112690000030}, {f:25,p:112690000037}, {f:25,p:112690000038}, {f:25,p:112690000039}, {f:25,p:112690000040}, {f:25,p:112690000041}, {f:25,p:112690000042}, {f:25,p:112690000056}, {f:25,p:112690000057}, {f:25,p:112690000058}, {f:25,p:112690000059}, {f:25,p:112690000063}, {f:25,p:112690000069}, {f:25,p:112690000076}, {f:25,p:112690000083}, {f:25,p:112690000084}, {f:25,p:112690000104}, {f:25,p:112690000105}, {f:25,p:112690000108}, {f:25,p:112690000117}, {f:25,p:112690000130}, {f:25,p:112690000131}, {f:25,p:112690000132}]"
  },
  {
    correo: "ANGIE.PULIDO@SEGUROSDELESTADO.COM.CO",
    enviado: true,
    excel: true,
    fechaSolicitud: "08-10-2021",
    fechas: "[2021-07-31]",
    idCliente: 34170,
    pdf: true,
    planes: "[{f:25,p:110020904148}, {f:25,p:112690000002}, {f:25,p:112690000006}, {f:25,p:112690000007}, {f:25,p:112690000019}, {f:25,p:112690000025}, {f:25,p:112690000026}, {f:25,p:112690000030}, {f:25,p:112690000037}, {f:25,p:112690000038}, {f:25,p:112690000039}, {f:25,p:112690000040}, {f:25,p:112690000041}, {f:25,p:112690000042}, {f:25,p:112690000056}, {f:25,p:112690000057}, {f:25,p:112690000058}, {f:25,p:112690000059}, {f:25,p:112690000063}, {f:25,p:112690000069}, {f:25,p:112690000076}, {f:25,p:112690000083}, {f:25,p:112690000084}, {f:25,p:112690000104}, {f:25,p:112690000105}, {f:25,p:112690000108}, {f:25,p:112690000117}, {f:25,p:112690000130}, {f:25,p:112690000131}, {f:25,p:112690000132}]"
  }
];

/**let columnsArray;
for (const key in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    columnsArray = Object.keys(json[key]);

    columnsArray.reverse();
  }
}

console.log(columnsArray);*/

/* hola a todo  */

/*
Este es el resultado que necesito sacar
fechaSolicitud
idCliente
correo
enviado
pdf
excel
fechas
planes



*/

/**
 * Ya que hablamos de que la variable json es un arreglo de objetos
 * podemos hacer lo siguiente
 */
const matriz = [];
for (const j in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(j)) {

    // Obtenemos las key de cada json
    const keys = Object.keys(json[j]);
    // Obtenemos los valores de cada key que existe en cada json
    const values = Object.values(json[j]);
    /**
     * Inicializamos el arreglo a llenar con el orden especifico,
     * se crea con las posiciones y con un valor pordefecto,
     * en mi caso les puse undefined pero se puede dar el que se desee.
     */
    const arreglo = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];

    // Recorremos las
    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
      if (key === 'fechaSolicitud') {
        arreglo[0] = values[i];
      } else if (key === 'idCliente') {
        arreglo[1] = values[i];
      } else if (key === 'correo') {
        arreglo[2] = values[i];
      } else if (key === 'enviado') {
        arreglo[3] = values[i];
      } else if (key === 'pdf') {
        arreglo[4] = values[i];
      } else if (key === 'excel') {
        arreglo[5] = values[i];
      } else if (key === 'fechas') {
        arreglo[6] = values[i];
      } else if (key === 'planes') {
        arreglo[7] = values[i];
      }

      if (i === keys.length - 1) {
        matriz.push(arreglo);
      }
    });
  }
  console.log(matriz);
}
```

Ya que requieres la información de una manera puntual, toca hacer el proceso manual.

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta lo unico que necesitaba herar ordenar las keys de el json con su valor que quedara asi: fechaSolicitud <br>
idCliente<br>
correo<br>
enviado<br>
pdf<br>
excel<br>
fechas<br>
planes<br> te dejo el link donde esta haciendo un ejemplo [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ejercicio-con-objectos-dc3ti?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)